# Statement works in database, but fails in Java code -

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

```
CREATE USER Person identified by 2012;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO Person;
```

These statements are successfully executed by Oracle 11g (GUI). But, when I copy and paste the above statement exactly and try to execute it by using `executeUpdate(String sql)`, I get the exception below. Why?

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

Comment: Don't you need to have your queries separated? I mean two separate `executeUpdate`.

Comment: You try to execute them as they are, i.e. together ?

Comment: @MatinKh - I did not know that was necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependend on your database jdbc driver, the driver will not support executing two statements in one "executeUpdate". You have to do something like:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
for(String statement : statements) {
    stmt.addBatch(statement);
}
stmt.executeBatch();
```

Comment: Thanks ! I wanted to add some extra info about executeUpdate vs executeBatch() here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143053/how-effective-is-executebatch-on-a-prepared-statement

Answer (score 4):

You should not give a two different SQL statements as one. There is no way that you can JDBC driver will  execute two statements passed as one string.

try to execute them as

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE USER Person identified by 2012");
stmt.executeUpdate("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO Person;");
```

That should do. Cheers.