# hibernate entitymanager bulk update

Tags: hibernate, entitymanager

I am having following method

```
    @Transactional
@JamonMonitored(type = MonitorType.DAO, tag = "name=JpaKeywordDao,method=save")
public void save(List<KeywordEntity> keywords) {
    Query updateBidStmt = entityManager.createNativeQuery(SQL_UPDATE_KEYWORD_BIDS_WITH_OPTIONAL_BID);
    for (KeywordEntity keyword : keywords) {
        updateBidStmt.setParameter(PARAM_INTERNAL_KEYWORD_ID, keyword.getInternalId());
        updateBidStmt.setParameter(PARAM_BROAD_MATCH_BID, keyword.getBroadMatchBid() == null ? -1 : keyword.getBroadMatchBid());
        updateBidStmt.setParameter(PARAM_CONTENT_MATCH_BID, keyword.getContentMatchBid() == null ? -1 : keyword.getContentMatchBid());
        updateBidStmt.setParameter(PARAM_EXACT_MATCH_BID, keyword.getExactMatchBid() == null ? -1 : keyword.getExactMatchBid());
        updateBidStmt.setParameter(PARAM_PHRASE_MATCH_BID, keyword.getPhraseMatchBid() == null ? -1 : keyword.getPhraseMatchBid());
        updateBidStmt.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

I guess this method executes update 1 by 1. I want to do this in bulk as it is putting load on server.

Please help.

Comment: That depends -  have you actually _looked_ at the generated SQL? For example, with MySQL - [this might be of interest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307760/mysql-and-jdbc-with-rewritebatchedstatements-true).

Comment: protected static final String SQL_UPDATE_KEYWORD_BIDS_WITH_OPTIONAL_BID = "UPDATE {h-schema}MSN_KEYWORDS set "
            + "     BROAD_MATCH_AMT = nullif(:broadMatchBid, -1), "
            + "     CONTENT_MATCH_AMT = nullif(:contentMatchBid, -1),"
            + "     EXACT_MATCH_AMT = nullif(:exactMatchBid, -1),"
            + "     PHRASE_MATCH_AMT = nullif(:phraseMatchBid, -1), "
            + "     UPDATE_DT = SYSDATE "
            + "where OBJECT_ID = :internalKeywordId";


This is the SQL.