# How to calculate how many rows to insert at a time, considering mysql's max_allowed_packet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to synchronize data from one database to another in MySQL, using Java.
To improve performance, I try to use MySQL bulk insert syntax:

```
insert into table xxx(...) values (row1...) (row2...).
```

The problem is, how many rows should I insert at a time, so as not to violate the MySQL's `max_allowed_packet` setting?

Comment: given that we know neither the average size of your rows, nor the value that your `max_allowed_packet` is set to, an answer is impossible.

Comment: how do i know the average size of the rows? I am actually working on a general sync program that could be used to sync different kind of tables. so the average size cannot be pre-determined.

Comment: yes. it can. `show table status`. or you just track it as you build the query and compare it to the max packet size.

Comment: Why use Java at all? MySQL already does replication, and it already has dump and load facilities.

Comment: @pala_ so I should just measure the sql size and compare it againt the max packet size? what about prepared statement?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do those calculations yourself because MySQL Connector/J will take care of the details if you

- use `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` in your connection URL
- use `addBatch()` and `executeBatch()`.

For more details see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26313288/2144390).

Comment: great! thanks you for telling me the rewriteBatchedStatements setting. it is useful!