# JDBC PreparedStatement Batch continue insert on error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, weblogic

Hello guy I create a Batch with a `PreparedStatement` in java like this

```
for(Item  item: list){
    ps.setString(1, item.getSome());
    ps.setString(2, item.getFoo());
    ps.setString(3, item.getBatman());
    statement.addBatch();

    if (++count % batchSize == 0) {
        results = ps.executeBatch(); //execute parcial batch

        if (results != null)
           System.out.println(results.length);
    }

}
results= ps.executeBatch(); //execute rest of batch
```

The datebase server is a MySQL, in table to insert I have several restrictions

By these restrictions when I insert generates errors

**I want run the batch and omit errors**, at this moment throw a Exception a ends batch

Before I create the batch I have a Big for the save one by one like

```
//seudocode level
For item
Try{
   insert item
}catch(E){nothing happens}
```

But it is very slow, in some cases, the batch procces 4000 item, insert 1500 and omit the rest

How do I do with the batch?

**EDIT**

I use weblogic to make conections with this driver `mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.0.3-bin`

I test this properties

1.

```
continueBatchOnError=true
```

2.

```
rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

3.

```
continueBatchOnError=true
rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

And add `connection.setAutoCommit(false);` but continues throw the exception in duplicates

**EDIT**

forgot to mention, I use for connection Hibernate + Spring

The only For-Save example is made in Hibernate, but for performance i tried use a JDBC Batch, in other procces in the webapp also use JDBC with the connection from Hibernate and works well

This is the full code

```
@Transactional
public void saveMany(final List<Item> items) {
    getMySqlSession().doWork(new Work() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("INSERT INTO `FRT_DB`.`ITEM` ");
            sb.append("( ");
            sb.append("`masterID`, ");
            sb.append("`agent`, ");
            sb.append("`rangeID`) ");
            sb.append("VALUES ");
            sb.append("( ");
            sb.append("?, ");
            sb.append("?, ");
            sb.append("?) ");

            int[] results = null;

            PreparedStatement ps = null;

            try {
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                ps = connection.prepareStatement(sb.toString());


                final int batchSize = 250;
                int count = 0;

                for (Item item : items) {

                    if (item.getMasterId() != null) {
                        ps.setInt(1, item.getMasterId());
                    } else
                        ps.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

                    if (item.getAgent() != null) {
                        ps.setString(2, item.getAgent());
                    } else
                        ps.setNull(2, Types.VARCHAR);

                    if (item.getRangeId() != null)
                        ps.setInt(3, item.getRangeId());
                    else
                        ps.setNull(3, Types.INTEGER);

                    ps.addBatch();

                    if (++count % batchSize == 0) {
                        results = ps.executeBatch();

                        if (results != null)
                            System.out.println(results.length);

                    }

                }

                results= ps.executeBatch();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

This produce next Exception

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '1-000002725' for key
>   'masterID'

But I need to continue

spring + hibernate settings interfere with the properties of jdbc? I dont know

Comment: Are you using the "MySQL Connector/J" JDBC driver? If so, the default behaviour should be `continueBatchOnError=true`, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: @GordThompson I use weblogic for the connection, I add the propertie `continueBatchOnError=true` and restart but problem persist throw exeption in first insert `ps.executeBatch();` later read this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307760/mysql-and-jdbc-with-rewritebatchedstatements-true) and add this `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` but still the Exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it can be summed up in one word `IGNORE`

When you run the batch with this

```
sb.append("INSERT IGNORE INTO `FRT_DB`.`ITEM` ");
```

This **NOT throw a Exception** realted with constrains, this pass over, and still old data in your rows

If you need save the 'new data' you change for `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` Statement, but , right now think dont need it.

Commit or rollback is not necesary in your code `@Transactional` work for you.

Your big `try {` only crash in SqlException not in BatchUpdateException

You  only need add `allowMultiQueries` beacuse other and default `true`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: I am using mssql, in which their is no ignore (says invalid object). Is their any option for this in jdbcTemplate.