# How to do not rollback transaction on insert failure (Spring+Hibernate)?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-transactions, hibernate-5.x

I am writing batch processing. I load CSV file (up to  10.000 rows) and I insert them in database. I do not want my processing to fail in case of duplicates.

Is it possible to do such `INSERT` in single transaction, catch exception for duplicates, proceed with `INSERT` and commit the transaction?
Or, is there no other way than transaction-per-INSERT pattern?

Currently, my transaction is always rolled back for `PersistenceException`, no matter how I configure noRollbackFor attribute for my transaction (`Transactional` annotation).

I use Spring Boot 1.4.2 (with Hibernate 5 and Spring Framework 4.3.5).

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852748/jdbc-preparedstatement-batch-continue-insert-on-error. Might help.

Comment: Have you tried `try{} catch(DataAccessException e){//do nothing}` inside the `@Transactional` method?

Comment: yes, it still rollbacks. Debuging shows that  PersistenceException is burried inside entityManager...

Comment: PersistenceException extends RuntimeException so I think catching it and doing a noop is not gonna work: http://codetreasury.com/2014/01/25/springs-transactional-important-points/ Do you have other transactional methods being called from your @Transactional method? If so, read the link and see if it applies. You could perhaps show your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDBC PreparedStatement Batch continue insert on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852748/jdbc-preparedstatement-batch-continue-insert-on-error)

Comment: @Bartosz Bilicki, How have you fixed the issue? I am also facing the same. I want Spring to ignore duplicate Key Exceptions and proceed further. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343137/problem-in-handling-unit-of-work-using-hibernate-jpa

Comment: @AlagammalP I have choosen to check if rows I am about to insert are already present, and reject rows where primary key was already existing. It somewhat complicates and slows down the process, but
it provides good error reporting (list existing primary keys). Note that check-then insert pattern does not work if there are multiple concurrent upload processes.