# fast way to insert into database using java

Tags: java, mysql, database, performance, jdbc

I was curious about how fast we can execute MySQL query through a loop in Java and well it is taking extremely long time with the code I wrote. I am sure there is a faster way to do it. Here is the piece of code that is executing the query.

```
PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO books.author VALUES (?,?,?)");
for (int i=0;i<100000;i++)
{
       ps.setString(1,test[i][0]);
       ps.setString(2,test[i][1]);
       ps.setString(3,test[i][2]);
       ps.addBatch();
}
int []p=ps.executeBatch();
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: It will likely be faster to execute it in **smaller** batches.

Comment: in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784197/efficient-way-to-do-batch-inserts-with-jdbc), the conclusion reached was that the way you're doing it is the fastest, as the statement only needs to be parsed once. It's for Oracle instead of MySql, but I think the same consideration applies here.

Comment: OK, I will try creating smaller batches and execute, to see if it makes any impact on time taken to execute. Thank you

Comment: Since you're using MySQL you may want to use `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` as discussed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313288/2144390).

Comment: wow! that one statement reduced the time taken to insert 100k values from around 20min+ to just 5 seconds. That is amazing. Thank you very much Gord Thompson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic approach is correct. Since you are using MySQL you may want to add `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to your connection URL as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26313288/2144390). It has been known to significantly speed up batch INSERT operations to MySQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of other things that kick in when you have a huge batch.  So going "too" big will slow down the rows/second.  This depends on a few settings, the specific table schema, and other things.  I have see a too-big batch run twice as slow as a more civilized batch.

Think of the overhead of parsing the query as being equivalent to inserting an extra 10 rows.  Based on that Rule of Thumb, a batch insert of 1000 rows is within 1% of the theoretical maximum speed.

It *may* be faster to create a file with all the rows and do `LOAD DATA`.  But, again, this depends on various settings, etc.