# how to minimize the execution time for a java program?

Tags: java, execution-time

I have created a program in java for entering 1000 random numbers into two different database one for odd numbers and one for even. The code is executing fine but it takes nearly a minute to execute. How can I minimize the Execution time?

Here is the code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test1 extends Thread {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int evencount = 0;
    int oddcount = 0;
    int breakcon = 0;
    int breakcon1 = 0;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1" + "?useSSL=false", "root",
            "1234");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2" + "?useSSL=false", "root",
            "1234");

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        for (int n = 1; n <= 1000; n++) {
            Random r = new Random();
            int val = r.nextInt(100000);

            if (val % 2 == 0) {
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(" insert into try values (?)");
                ps.setInt(1, val);
                ps.executeUpdate();
                ps.addBatch();
                breakcon = breakcon + 1;
                if (breakcon % 500 == 0 || breakcon == val)
                    ps.executeBatch();
                evencount++;

            } else {
                try {

                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    PreparedStatement ps3 = conn.prepareStatement(" insert into try1 values (?)");
                    ps3.setInt(1, val);
                    ps3.executeUpdate();
                    ps3.addBatch();
                    breakcon1 = breakcon1 + 1;
                    if (breakcon1 % 500 == 0 || breakcon1 == val)
                        ps3.executeBatch();

                    oddcount++;

                }

                catch (Exception e2) {
                    System.out.println(e2);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00000");
    System.out.println("Execution time is " + formatter.format((end - start) / 1000d) + " seconds");
    System.out.println(oddcount + evencount);

}
}
```

Comment: I would look at SQL batching.

Comment: @JoeC how should I do that? Please explain

Comment: These Kind of questions is better asks at [codereview.SE]. Because it is about improving running code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to do batch INSERTS with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784197/efficient-way-to-do-batch-inserts-with-jdbc)

Comment: use `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` only one

Comment: Hint: if you need to copy and paste the same text twice to get over question restrictions **you are asking a bad question**. It will get downvoted and closed. Post output from a profiler. Describe _where_ your code is slow. Describe how fast you _need_ it to be? I reckon this could be done in a couple hundred millis with batching and one thread for each type of number.

Comment: @Jens rather remove `Class.forName()` completely... that's a real blast from the past.

Comment: You can not run it; that'd save a lot of time.

Comment: Change Random random = new Random to ThreadLocalRandom.current(). It has better performance.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `ps.executeUpdate();`  (and `ps3.executeUpdate();`) after each time you `setInt` - do it only once *after* the for-loop. That's the whole point of using `addBatch` (aggregate inserts/updates and executing them all at once).

As Boris mentioned in the comment below, it would make the execution much faster if you also turn on `rewriteBatchedStatements`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26313288/1057429) how it can be achieved.

Comment: I guess turning on `rewriteBatchedStatements` would help too?

Comment: @BoristheSpider good point, thanks!