# Optimising MySQL INSERT with many VALUES (),(),();

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to improve my Java app's performance and I'm focusing at this point on one end point which has to insert a large amount of data into mysql.

I'm using plain JDBC with the MariaDB Java client driver:

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO data (" +
                    "fId, valueDate, value, modifiedDate" +
                    ") VALUES (?,?,?,?)") {
    for (DataPoint dp : datapoints) {
        stmt.setLong(1, fId);
        stmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(dp.getDate().getTime()));
        stmt.setDouble(3, dp.getValue());
        stmt.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(modifiedDate.getTime()));
        stmt.addBatch();
    }        
    int[] results = statement.executeBatch();
}
```

From populating the new DB from dumped files, I know that [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) is important and I've got that set to 536,870,912 bytes.

In https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-optimization.html it states that:

> If you are inserting many rows from the same client at the same time,
>   use INSERT statements with multiple VALUES lists to insert several
>   rows at a time. This is considerably faster (many times faster in some
>   cases) than using separate single-row INSERT statements. If you are
>   adding data to a nonempty table, you can tune the
>   [bulk_insert_buffer_size variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size) to make data insertion even faster.
>   See [Section 5.1.7, “Server System Variables”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size).

On my DBs, this is set to 8MB

I've also read about [`key_buffer_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size) (currently set to 16MB).

I'm concerned that these last 2 might not be enough. I can do some rough calculations on the JSON input to this algorithm because it looks someething like this:

```
[{"actualizationDate":null,"data":[{"date":"1999-12-31","value":0},
{"date":"2000-01-07","value":0},{"date":"2000-01-14","value":3144},
{"date":"2000-01-21","value":358},{"date":"2000-01-28","value":1049},
{"date":"2000-02-04","value":-231},{"date":"2000-02-11","value":-2367},
{"date":"2000-02-18","value":-2651},{"date":"2000-02-25","value":-
393},{"date":"2000-03-03","value":1725},{"date":"2000-03-10","value":-
896},{"date":"2000-03-17","value":2210},{"date":"2000-03-24","value":1782},
```

and it looks like the 8MB configured for `bulk_insert_buffer_size` could easily be exceeded, if not `key_buffer_size` as well.

But the MySQL docs only make mention of `MyISAM` engine tables, and I'm currently using `InnoDB` tables.

I can set up some tests but it would be good to know how this will break or degrade, if at all.

[EDIT] I have `--rewriteBatchedStatements=true`. In fact here's my connection string:

```
jdbc:p6spy:mysql://myhost.com:3306/mydb\
    ?verifyServerCertificate=true\
    &useSSL=true\
    &requireSSL=true\
    &cachePrepStmts=true\
    &cacheResultSetMetadata=true\
    &cacheServerConfiguration=true\
    &elideSetAutoCommits=true\
    &maintainTimeStats=false\
    &prepStmtCacheSize=250\
    &prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048\
    &rewriteBatchedStatements=true\
    &useLocalSessionState=true\
    &useLocalTransactionState=true\
    &useServerPrepStmts=true
```

(from https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration )

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26313288/2144390) may be of interest.

Comment: You can simply execute the batch every ####  insertion. Optimizing this will probably be a pain where you can simply execute the batch from time to time. PS: Be aware that "_This is considerably faster (many times faster in some cases) than using separate single-row INSERT_" is not about prepared statement, a batch is sending one compiled query (based on the DB) and a batch of parameters. It is more efficient than executing an insert query on each iteration.

Comment: @AxelH yes, great point, something I was too busy to realise...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative is to execute the batch from time to time. This allows you to reduce the size of the batchs and let you focus on more important problems.

```
int batchSize = 0;

for (DataPoint dp : datapoints) {
    stmt.setLong(1, fId);
    stmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(dp.getDate().getTime()));
    stmt.setDouble(3, dp.getValue());
    stmt.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(modifiedDate.getTime()));
    stmt.addBatch();

    //When limit reach, execute and reset the counter
    if(batchSize++ >= BATCH_LIMIT){
        statement.executeBatch();

        batchSize = 0;
    }
}        

// To execute the remaining items
if(batchSize > 0){
    statement.executeBatch();
}
```

I generally use a constant or a parameter based on the DAO implementation to be more dynamic but a batch of 10_000 row is a good start.

```
private static final int BATCH_LIMIT = 10_000;
```

Note that this is not necessary to clear the batch after an execution. Even if this is not specified in [`Statement.executeBatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch--) documentation, this is in the [JDBC specification 4.3](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_3-mrel3-eval-spec/jdbc4.3-fr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1525325028_7d950aab9aa4c3e59fcfe23e208a9228)

> 14 Batch Updates
> 14.1 Description of Batch Updates
> 14.1.2 Successful Execution
>
> Calling the method executeBatch closes the calling Statement object’s current result set if one is open.
> The statement’s batch is reset to empty once executeBatch returns.

The management of the result is a bit more complicated but you can still concatenate the results if you need them. This can be analyzed at any time since the `ResultSet` is not needed anymore.

Comment: It's a shame there's no method on `Statement` giving the number of bytes already added to the batch. It would be great to generify the handling somehow to set the batch count dependent on bytes added.

Comment: Calling `clearBatch()` shouldn't be necessary; that should be done automatically on `executeBatch()`. From the JDBC 4.3 specification (section 14.1.2) : _"The statement’s batch is reset to empty once
`executeBatch` returns."_

Comment: I will check once I reach my laptop @MarkRotteveel, I quickly checked the documentation of the method but it was not specified so I preferred to be safe ;) didn't went to the jdbc specifications. Thanks for that by the way!

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel, I have adapted the answer based on your input. I should take a bit more time on that specification, I never really took the time to overview it.