# aurora 5.7 to 8.0 upgrade slow bulk insert performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I recently upgraded from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0.32, and I'm encountering significant performance issues with bulk inserts. Here's the context:

- **Database Engine**: InnoDB
- **Original Version**: MySQL 5.7
- **Current Version**: MySQL 8.0.32
- **Task**: Fetching 10,000 records from RDS and inserting them into another table.

**Performance Issue**:

- With MySQL 5.7, it took about 2 minutes to process 10,000 records.
- After upgrading to MySQL 8.0.32, the same operation now takes over 10 minutes.

[Here my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKagL.png)

**Additional Details**:

- Initially, even Select queries took over 10 minutes, but I managed to reduce this to 5 seconds by setting `range_optimizer_max_mem_size` to 0.
- The bulk insert part is notably slower in MySQL 8.0.32 compared to 5.7.

**Attempted Solution**:

- I tried adjusting `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`, but it didn't improve the performance.

I'm looking for suggestions or solutions to improve the bulk insert performance in MySQL 8.0.32. Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have resolved it for myself.

Adding "rewriteBatchedStatements" to the database URL resolved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you fixed it! Please add an Answer with details of how this fixed things so that future readers will benefit from your experience. You are also welcome to Accept your own Answer.

Comment: I did a quick search. Found this explanation of `rewriteBatchedStatements`: [MySQL and JDBC with rewriteBatchedStatements=true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26313288/174777)

Comment: Aurora is mysql compatible, but is not mysql as amazon changed significant part of its code.